# Numbers close to the signed 64 bit integer limit casues unix time not to format

Tags: c++, integer

I have a function to format a Unix timestamp to date and time string

```
std::string format_time_t(time_t time) {
    std::tm *ptm = std::localtime(&time);
    char buffer[32];
    std::strftime(buffer, 32, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p", ptm);
    return buffer;
}
```

This works, however when trying to format `9223372036854775807` I get a segmentation fault, I get the same result trying numbers smaller like `92233720368547750`.

I tried removing digits and found `9223372036854775` formats correctly (`08/17/292278994 02:12 AM`)

I'm not sure what the max number I can get to work is.

Why is this happening and how would I be able to format the max signed 64 bit integer?

I was expecting any number up to the 64 bit integer limit to format correctly, as numbers higher than the 32 bit integer limit work.

Comment: I don't suppose we can talk you into using `<chrono>`?

Comment: In `struct tm` the years field is `int tm_year`. The code is probably overflowing that `int`.

Comment: ah alright, how would I use chrono to format the date?

Comment: You know, I've never pushed it that far. Lemme see if I can prove that it works before Howard Hinnant posts his answer.

Comment: Looks like the best you can do with `tm` is somewhere around 67,769,429,938,567,200 (calc has lost some digits of precision at that point)

Comment: What C++ Standard can you compile to? What I have in mind is C++20 or an extra library.

Comment: Right now I'm using 17 but could compile to C++20

Comment: You get a segmentation fault because you don't check the return value of [`std::localtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime): it returns a `nullptr` and sets `errno` to `EOVERFLOW` if the argument is too large. Also, you don't check if [`std::strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) succeeds (i.e., returns a non-zero value), but that's another bug.

Comment: C++20 has a civil calendar limit of `[year::min(), year::max()]`.  Where these two years are specified to be -32767 and 32767.  Even this is overkill.  The civil calendar models the solar system to about 1 day in 4000 years.  It really doesn't make any sense to try to use the civil calendar beyond `[year::min(), year::max()]`.  And 63 signed bits of seconds lives out towards 292 billion years.  So chrono isn't going to help with this one.

Comment: That (that being it wasn't gonna work) is what I was finding via brute force. Didn't know what the reasonable limits were, just that I was past them.

Answer (score 4):

So from the comments under the question, one gets the idea that you're probably going to have to roll your own on this one.  The std libraries have limits and those limits are there to ensure that the typical user doesn't have to pay for functionality that is normally not needed.

But if you want to roll your own, it really isn't that hard.  And `<chrono>` actually can help.

Start here:  [chrono-Compatible Low-Level Date Algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html)

This link contains public domain algorithms for writing your own date library.  And these algorithms have a **very** large range of validity.  For this job you'll need `civil_from_days`.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <tuple>

template <class Int>
constexpr
std::tuple<Int, unsigned, unsigned>
civil_from_days(Int z) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits >= 18,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit unsigned integer");
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<Int>::digits >= 20,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit signed integer");
    z += 719468;
    const Int era = (z >= 0 ? z : z - 146096) / 146097;
    const unsigned doe = static_cast<unsigned>(z - era * 146097);          // [0, 146096]
    const unsigned yoe = (doe - doe/1460 + doe/36524 - doe/146096) / 365;  // [0, 399]
    const Int y = static_cast<Int>(yoe) + era * 400;
    const unsigned doy = doe - (365*yoe + yoe/4 - yoe/100);                // [0, 365]
    const unsigned mp = (5*doy + 2)/153;                                   // [0, 11]
    const unsigned d = doy - (153*mp+2)/5 + 1;                             // [1, 31]
    const unsigned m = mp < 10 ? mp+3 : mp-9;                              // [1, 12]
    return std::tuple<Int, unsigned, unsigned>(y + (m <= 2), m, d);
}

std::string
format_time_t(std::time_t time)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;
    using days = duration<int64_t, ratio<86400>>;
    time_point<system_clock, seconds> tp{seconds{time}};
    auto tpd = floor<days>(tp);
    auto tod = tp - tpd;
    auto [y, m, d] = civil_from_days(tpd.time_since_epoch().count());
    auto h = floor<hours>(tod);
    tod -= h;
    auto M = floor<minutes>(tod);
    auto fmt2 = [](auto i)
                {
                    if (i < 10)
                        return '0' + to_string(i);
                    return to_string(i);
                };
    auto s = fmt2(m) + '/' + fmt2(d) + '/' + fmt2(y) + ' ';
    string am = "AM";
    if (h < 12h)
    {
        if (h == 0h)
            h = 12h;
    }
    else
    {
        am = "PM";
        if (h != 12h)
            h -= 12h;
    }
    s += fmt2(h.count()) + ':' + fmt2(M.count()) + ' ' + am;
    return s;
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << format_time_t(std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::max()) << '\n';
}
```

If you really want to understand how `civil_from_days` works, it is at the [link](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html).  All it does is take a count of days before/after 1970-01-01 and returns a `{y, m, d}` triple.  And the range is large enough to handle this question if 64 bit arithmetic is used.

Now `format_time_t` just has to create a `days` duration (this is all assuming C++17, `std::chrono::days` exists in C++20), and use that to split the `time_point` into a date and time-of-day.

The date is sent into `civil_from_days` to get the `{y, m, d}` triple.  And the time-of-day is split into `{H, M}` using chrono.

Finally a little 2-digit formatting helper is created (to handle leading zeroes).  And the hours are adjusted into the 12-hour AM/PM format.

For `numeric_limits<int64_t>::max()` seconds this program outputs:

```
12/04/292277026596 03:30 PM
```

I purposefully neglected your local time zone.  The above is UTC.  It turns out that billions of years in the future we're no longer using time zones. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`std::localtime` is not guaranteed to succeed. It may fail to convert the argument and in this case it returns a null pointer. You neglect to check for and handle that situation.

On a POSIX system, if a null pointer is returned, you can also check `errno` for `EOVERFLOW`, which indicates that the argument is out-of-range.

You similarly forget to verify whether `strftime` succeeded by comparing its return value to `0`. If the buffer is too small, `strftime` returns `0` and then the buffer contents are indeterminate.

Comment: (edit: no idea how to make code format in a comment) Hows this? any improvements I could make?

```
std::string format_time_t(time_t time) {
    std::tm *ptm = std::localtime(&time);

    if (ptm != nullptr) {
        char buffer[32];
        if (std::strftime(buffer, 32, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p", ptm) != 0) {
            return buffer;
        }
    }

    return "Unknown";
}
```

Comment: @lucaslah Formatting in comments works with single backticks and there must not be any space following/preceding it.

Comment: @lucaslah Looks ok. Note that`%p`'s interpretation will depend on the active C locale.